# Can I connect with different databases and import data from tables using Hibernate? without a predefined object class

Tags: java, database, hibernate, import, jooq

I want to build a Java application which can work with different databases and import data from specific tables in these databases.

But this should be dynamically, User will choose the database type and enter the required parameters in order to connect, then after successfully connecting to the database, I want to display all tables in the schema and user will choose one of them to export data from.

I have tried to use Hibernate and did the connection successfully to different databases and did the basic operations (Add, delete and update). But, when I have tried to make a dynamic mapping, to be able to retrieve all databases tables that already exist, it didn't work correctly. 
I think theoretically from ORM perspective, this is not possible. I am not sure if I am right or wrong.

Do you have any recommendations regarding Hibernate or any other frameworks that could help?

Edit:

After some search I found some people talking about JOOQ for bottom-up database modeling, and Hibernate is used for up-down data modeling.

Have you ever used JOOQ before? Is it fit to my requirements?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why you would attempt to use Hibernate for this.  Hibernate (or any ORM) makes writing code easy when you have a *fixed data model*.  In your case, you should just be using essentially straight JDBC.

JOOQ (and [SqlBuilder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/)) are libraries that you can use alongside JDBC to assist with writing correct SQL statements.